# responsive menu in layouts/main.php

Tags: php, jquery, css, yii, responsive-design

I have a problem and I couldn't solve it...

[What I want](http://jsfiddle.net/czLLzj24/6/)

**layouts/main.php**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <?php
        $menular = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                                ->select('m.idmenu, m.menuparent_id, m.url, m.title_'.Yii::app()->language)
                                ->from ('menu m')
                                ->where('m.menuparent_id=0 and m.active="1"')
                                ->order('m.idmenu asc')->queryAll();

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($menular as $menu){
            if($menu['url'] == '#')
                $echoUrl = 'javascript:void(0);';
            else
                $echoUrl = $baseUrl.'/'.Yii::app()->language.$menu["url"];

            echo "<li class=''>";
            echo "<a href='".$echoUrl."' title='".$menu['title_'.Yii::app()->language]."'>".$menu['title_'.Yii::app()->language]."</a>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    ?>
</div>
```

In this *scene* script isn't assign `active` class to `li`..

So, please help me to solve this problem.

I think I can explain what's the problem.
Thanks.

P.S: `css` and `script` codes are the same with my *layout file*.

Comment: If it's a javascript function not working, then ther eis probably something wrong with your js. Can you share with us your EXACT script file?

Comment: Thanks for response. But I'm using the same js with which I shared it top of the question (in link).

Answer (score 1):

you can use one of the below options to confirm what controller OR action it is, then you can assign active class to the menu if it belongs to the page which is loaded.

1. Get the controller which is being called

   ```
   Yii::app()->controller->id
   ```
2. Check the action which is being called.

   ```
   Yii::app()->controller->route
   ```

Suppose for example if you want to assign active class to *"about us"* page and it is being called from site/about then

```
$active = Yii::app()->controller->route == "site/about" ? "active" : "";
echo "<li class='".$active."'>";
```

Comment: thanks for replying. but when I visit the `site/about` page, the all menu items has the `active` class.